# How to fix "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this[BASE_OBJECT][key]')"

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm new to React Native, and I'm trying to make a screen that has a popup. However, this errors appeared to me "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this[BASE_OBJECT][key]')" on the line that has this code

```
<PopupDialog
   dialogStyle={styles.popup}
   dialogTitle={<DialogTitle title="Contact Information" />}
ref={(popupDialog) => { this.popupDialog = popupDialog; }}
<View style={styles.dialogcontainer}>
  <Text style={styles.contacttext}>Email: react@gmail.com</Text>
  <Text style={styles.contacttext}>Phone: 1-800-code-all</Text>
  <Text style={styles.contacttext}>Twitter: @reactman</Text>
</View>
```

Could it be the dependencies in the Package.json? I tried to change it but the problem still the same. This is what I have in there "react-native-popup-dialog": "0.11.46"

Comment: Can you show more of your code? Is this inside a class?

Comment: It is inside a view tag. This is a link to the page https://snack.expo.io/@maghfuri/profile